# Instagram Subscription Callback using AWS API Gateway - Invalid SSL certificate

Tags: https, instagram-api, aws-api-gateway

We're trying to set up an instagram app and have worked our way through the process. We've now got stuck when trying to create a [subscription](https://www.instagram.com/developer/subscriptions/).

We have our app hosted on AWS API Gateway, which can only be deployed with HTTPS endpoints (it does not support unencrypted connections).
When we do the POST to get instagram to subscribe to a user using the following:

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' \
     -F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' \
     -F 'object=user' \
     -F 'aspect=media' \
     -F 'verify_token=myVerifyToken' \
     -F 'callback_url=https://YOUR-CALLBACK/URL' \
     https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/
```

then we get the following error:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "error_type": "APISubscriptionError",
        "code": 400,
        "error_message": "Invalid response"
    }
}
```

This happens whether we use our own HTTPS certificate that we have registered with API Gateway, or whether we use the stock AWS URL (https://xxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com) as the callback (which also has a valid HTTPS certificate). I have verified that the certificates are 'good' using SSLLabs (they both get an A result). Our code NEVER gets called (so it's not the return of the `hub.challenge` parameter that's the problem. Instagram seems to reject the HTTPS certificate when initiating the connection.

Interestingly, if we use the *same* certificate that we use with AWS API Gateway on a normal machine (EC2 instance) and change the DNS records to point to this server, then it all works as expected and the subscription works.

Has anyone got Instagram Subscriptions working when using AWS API Gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We contacted Instagram about this. The version of Python (or their libraries) that Instagram uses does not support SNI which API Gateway uses (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) so Instagram apps will not work if hosted on API Gateway unfortunately until Instagram upgrades their version of Python.

As Garrett points out below, whilst Instagram cannot post directly to API Gateway, you can put a cloudfront distribution in front of your API Gateway endpoints and let Instagram point to that. This will work.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post and felt deceived by the current answer given that API gateway can still be used despite instagram's api not accepting the SNI.

"Instagram apps will not work if hosted on API Gateway unfortunately until Instagram upgrades their version of Python." is not true.

All you need to do is put a CloudFront instance in front of the api gateway and it will work fine without needing an expensive SSL cert or anything.

I included screenshots of my config so that it may help someone in the future.

[Here is the first configuration screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzXcL.png)

[Behavior Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ7Bu.png)

[Origin Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCygO.png)

Comment: Garrett, good information. You can indeed put cloudfront in from of API Gateway and it will work. In that instance, instagram is POSTing to Cloudfront (not API Gateway) - a pendatic point perhaps.

Comment: Thanks!

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you have to use the default CloudFront SSL for this to work- otherwise you have to enable 'Custom SSL Support- All Clients', which costs $600/yr.

Playing around with this is frustrating- spent a lot of time waiting on distributions to update.

Comment: What are the problems you are having with the cloud front ssl? Did you take a look at the screenshots I posted of my configuration. I agree, waiting for distributions to update is a major pain. But after 3 or so times tinkering with it, I was glad I did. Especially considering it was free, and very convenient to modify. I have actually used SSL certificates from third parties before (like COMODO) and they are actually much more timely to get worked out when you need one re-issued. With that in mind, this was relatively effortless.

Answer (score 0):

To verify if this is a API Gateway issue have you tried to issue the same challenge request that Instagram is making to your API endpoint directly ?

If you haven't already, you should also try to [enable CloudWatch logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-stage-settings.html#how-to-stage-settings-console) on your API stage to debug the call.

Comment: Yep. Tried both of those. We can make the same request to our subscription callback endpoint directly and it echoes back the hub.challenge parameter. We already have cloudwatch logging enabled, and can see from the logs (and cloudwatch metrics) that our Lambda process that's behind API Gateway doesn't even get called (which makes sense if instagram is rejecting the HTTPS certificate as it won't actually make the underlying HTTP GET call)

Comment: Just to be super clear, when I wrote "API endpoint", I meant to `https://xxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` and your custom domain.  Do requests to these endpoints via curl succeed or fail?

Comment: Calls to HTTPS://xxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com fail with the same SSL error as our custom domain